# two way ssl handshake fails with no suitable certificate found

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to create a http client to support mutual auth with the server and the request fails with "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException"

When I turn on debugging I see the following

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
```

I have checked my trustsore and keystore and they have the complete chain.

Comment: Your server's truststore doesn't trust your client certificate.

Comment: The client and server certs are signed by the same intermediate and root ca

Comment: Irrelevant. The server truststore doesn't trust the signer. That is the meaning of the message.

Comment: I have the pem format of the cert, private key and the ca and a curl using these three works but from the java client it fails.

Note that i am not using "-k" or "--insecure" with my curl

Comment: Sigh. You need to introduce the signing CA certificate into the server's trust store, and the client's private key, signed certificate, and trust chain into Ithe client keystore.

Comment: (edited) @EJP: this may mean server didn't _specify_ the CA, but server isn't required to specify all CAs it trusts, or any. OP: does keystore have the chain in a privateKeyEntry _not_ trustedCertEntry's, and did the trace show it loaded (to this context)? Is key/cert the right algorithm for the ciphersuite, and not too small/weak? Does cert/chain match `CertAuthorities` if other than `<Empty>`  in `***Certificate Request` just before `***ServerHelloDone`? Note if curl uses OpenSSL, as is common, it ignores mismatch of CA on client cert; JSSE doesn't.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes the keystore is in privatekey entry

`$keytool -v -list -keystore mykeystore.p12
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: 1
Creation date: Feb 4, 2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:`